# Running Gradle build - failed! JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm attempting to run my Ionic application in an Android emulator in Android Studio using the ionic command in terminal in VSCode:

```
ionic capacitor run android
```

But I get the following error when running:

```
[capacitor] × Running Gradle build - failed!
[capacitor] [error] 
[capacitor]         ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
[capacitor]         location of your Java installation.
[capacitor]
```

So I set the environment variables as seen here:
[image: JAVA_HOME]

[image: PATH]

But I still get the same error?

When I run the java command in the command line that all runs fine:
[image: JavaCMD]

Comment: Where does it say that it would work with JDK 17? Use the JDK bundled with Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Java JDK-11 is mostly compatible with android.

1. Add correct java path (mostly jre path).
2. Run the same command and check again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to running it with Android Studio:

```
ionic cap open android
```

Also you can check the doc https://capacitorjs.com/docs/android/troubleshooting.